# How to view the total price/cost in php from sql?

Tags: php, mysql

How to view the total price in php from sql?

Example:
SQL

```
Item               Price
Phone1             1200
Phone2             1341
Phone3             2140
Phone4              850
Phone5              903
                 ---------
      Total Price: 6434
```

Comment: Uh, maybe you should learn enough SQL to know what `group by` is.

Comment: Well, that doesn't look at all like SQL to me - please don't tell my boss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT sum(Price) FROM table"), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get sum() in SQL

```
SELECT sum(Price) FROM table
```

in PHP

```
$sum = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $sum += $row['Price'];
}
```